# 415 UNSUPPORTED MEDIA - API Post Javascript - Django

Tags: javascript, python, django, ajax, django-rest-framework

I am trying to create an API on my Django server but I am struggling to create a post method called by Javascript.

This is my APIview

class componentFrameAPI(APIView):

```
def get(self, request):
    componentAPI = component.objects.all()
    serializer = componentSerializer(componentAPI, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)

def post(self):
    serializer = componentSerializer(componentAPI, data=self.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        # serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

And this is my post request on Javascript.

```
let data = {componentName:"PostTest",componentBody:"TEST"}
datax = JSON.stringify(data)

var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest()
xhttp.open("POST","http://127.0.0.1:8000/myurl/", true)
xhttp.setRequestHeader('X-CSRFToken', csrftoken)
xhttp.setRequestHeader('contentType', 'application/json')    
xhttp.send(datax)
```

I continue to receive a 415 error and I really don't know what I am doing wrong.

NOTE: The GET method works fine.

Thanks for your help.

Giacomo

Comment: I am not sure about Django, but few thing you need to verify while requesting the rest end point make sure 'contentType', 'application/json' is also same in request and  rest end point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your are close but have a typo in `xhttp.setRequestHeader('contentType', 'application/json')`

Change that to

```
xhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')
```

And you should be fine
Full example

```
let data = {componentName:"PostTest",componentBody:"TEST"}
datax = JSON.stringify(data)

var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest()
xhttp.open("POST","http://127.0.0.1:8000/myurl/", true)
xhttp.setRequestHeader('X-CSRFToken', csrftoken)
xhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')    
xhttp.send(datax)
```